# Use of ParseGeopoint with google web services API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, parse-platform, geolocation, geocoding

I have a simple problem. There is a location A who's postal code and city is known. There are 3 other locations B1, B2 and B3 who's latitude and longitude is known. I need to find the distance between Ab1, ab2, ab3 and arrange them in ascending order. Im using parse, android.

To determine lat, long from postal code I tried using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) by reading an answer here. However the documentation has left me confused. Im unable to find a tutorial showing how exactly to use the API. Could someone please guide me. It says I need an API key but through the browser, I can view custom links so why wont I be able to do the same via HTTP requests via my android app?

Once I have the coordinates of A, B1, B2 and B3, I know how to store them as ParseGeo point for separate objects and use query to sort by distance in ascending/ descending order as needed.

Answer (score 1):

For a JSON result, you can probably just put `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[POSTAL CODE]`. If putting the postal code into google maps works, it should also work in this instance. You'll then need to parse the JSON or xml response, but there's lots out there for doing that (specifically for JSON check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)

Now for distance. Distance on the earth is not a Pythagorean problem, but rather a spherical mercator problem. To avoid extensive math, I'd use `Location` objects like so:

```
location1.distanceTo(location2);
```

More on `Location` here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: Parse has inbuilt parse geopoint that determines distance between two points that I will be using. Im confused why its written that there is a usage limit and an API key is needed to use google web services API when this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:400034|country:india works directly when placed into the browser.